# Why does ARC work for iOS 4.0+ only?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

What is the technical reason for ARC to be supported by iOS 4.0 and above only?

It is my understanding that it is a compiler feature, which merely inserts memory management related code automatically instead of requiring the developer to do so. From what I read the calls themselves remain the same - at least that's what Apples [Transitioning to ARC Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) implies.

As such, it should not involve features that have not been present in previous versions of iOS, and indeed ARC does work with iOS 4.0 despite having been introduced later.

I'm asking this question out of curiosity and don't actually need to make ARC work with iOS 3.x.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is for the same reason that automatic reference counting only supports 64-bit Snow Leopard as a minimum deployment target: ARC support requires certain features present only in a new enough version of the modern runtime. That modern runtime was introduced with iOS 4.0, so older iOS versions lack the runtime capable of handling some of the things required technically by ARC. If it were just keyed to OS versions, 32-bit Snow Leopard applications would be supported as well, but only the 64-bit runtime is the modern one there.

If you watch Apple's presentations from [WWDC 2011](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/), particularly the "Objective-C Advancements In-Depth," you'll see that a number of under-the-hood improvements have been made to speed up the retain / release process, as well as things like the faster `@autoreleasepool`. There's an entire section on runtime support in the [LLVM ARC specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#runtime). These improvements require more than just compiler support.

We already had to use the modern runtime for features like automatic synthesis of instance variables (as explained in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtVersionsPlatforms.html)), so this isn't a terrible surprise.

Even iOS 4.0 as a target lacks support for weak references, so there are clearly technical issues at play here. This isn't just a marketing strategy to drive developers to the newer versions, as has been asserted by others.

Comment: It is unlikely that ARC requires some feature of the x86-64 that is missing on i386 that prevents its imlementation. "Technical", "marketing", "resource", "management", "practical" etc. are all subjective terms. Unless someone from Apple chooses to chip in all answers to the OP's question are at best guesses. Indeed different folks at Apple, depending on their role, probably have different reasons! There is no "clearly" about it - note the use of "probably" and "guess" in other answers.

Comment: @CRD - Perhaps you should read the above Apple documentation where it states: "iPhone applications and 64-bit programs on Mac OS X v10.5 and later use the modern version of the runtime. Other programs (32-bit programs on Mac OS X desktop) use the legacy version of the runtime." This is not about x86-64 vs. i386, it's about runtime capabilities. As I've mentioned, there are technical differences between runtime versions shipped with each OS, and a new enough version of the runtime is required in order to support ARC. Backporting the newer runtimes to older OS versions is not feasible.

Comment: except ARC doesn't run on 10.5... which uses the modern runtime... and why doesn't the modern runtime run on i386... etc. We'll end up arguing Turing completeness next :-)

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was hoping for. Thank you very much Sir!

Comment: Brad, congrats on that little diamond of yours! You're *meant* to wear it ;)

Answer (score 4):

The [docs of Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) states that the dealloc chaining to super is handled in runtime in the case of ARC.

Answer (score 2):

The kind of a same question would be:

*Why is `NSRegularExpression` only supported by iOS 4.0+ and Mac OS X 10.7(Lion)+?*

You have fully working simulators of iOS 5.0(and 4.0 obviously) in Mac OS X 10.6.7(Snow Leopard) where you can easily use `NSRegularExpression`, but it's not supported by Mac OS X 10.6.7 itself.

And concerning your question: ARC was introduced with iOS 5.0. At that time there were not many iOS 3.x users anymore, so my opinion is that Apple was a bit too lazy to make ARC compatible with iOS 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the clang tool chain (required for ARC) does not build binaries compatible with iOS 3.x.

Also, there are a couple of C functions used in place of sending `-retain` and `-release` that might not be available in iOS 3.x

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1745876